# Using "shaded" in thmtools and add space below and above

Tags: thmtools

In the following example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
%   
\declaretheoremstyle[%
    spaceabove=60pt, spacebelow=60pt, % just for testing
    shaded={rulecolor=black,rulewidth=.5pt,bgcolor={rgb}{1,1,1}}
]{framed}

\declaretheorem[style=framed]{theorem}
%
\begin{document}    
\blindtext
%
\begin{theorem}
$ \int $ and some text
\end{theorem}
%
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

there will be no space added below and above. Without the shaded-declaration everything is fine. How can I achieve to add some space above and below?

Comment: You won't have these problems with `ntheorem` and the `framed` package. Further, shaded theorems will be able to break across pages, if necessary.

Comment: The problem with ntheorem is, that it's last release is from 2012 and sometimes it is not working as described, e.g. to use  \ensuremath{_\blacksquare} in the proof-environment as described on page 9 of the manual is not working. One has to add the package wasysym (at least I had to do this).

Comment: Personally, I never had any problem – which doesn't mean, of course, it can't have. But why don't you use, as an end-of-proof marker,  \textsc{q.e.d.}, or even E.O.Δ. ? ;ο)

Comment: Because I like the Halmos-tombstone I am using the square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an oversight in `thmtools`. The package defines `shaded` as adding `\begin{shadebox}` and `\end{shadebox}` around the theorem, but then the space settings are not taken into account.

You can redefine the `shaded` style by adding the settings explicitly. This also requires to load a few involved packages in  your own preamble to make the necessary settings available during the definition.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{shadethm}
\usepackage{thmdef-shaded}
%
\makeatletter
\define@key{thmdef}{shaded}[{}]{%
  \addtotheorempreheadhook[\thmt@envname]{%
      \setlength\shadedtextwidth{\linewidth}%
      \kvsetkeys{thmt@shade}{#1}\vspace{\thmt@style@spaceabove}\begin{shadebox}}%
    \addtotheorempostfoothook[\thmt@envname]{\end{shadebox}\vspace{\thmt@style@spacebelow}}%
  }
\makeatother

\declaretheoremstyle[%
    spaceabove=60pt, spacebelow=30pt, % just for testing
    shaded={rulecolor=black,rulewidth=.5pt,bgcolor={gray}{0.5}}
]{framed}

\declaretheorem[style=framed]{theorem}
%
\begin{document}    
\blindtext
%
\begin{theorem}
$ \int $ and some text
\end{theorem}
%
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Comment: I found a solution using `mdframed` :

```
\declaretheoremstyle[mdframed={outerlinewidth=6pt,
                               innertopmargin=6pt, 
                               innerbottommargin=6pt} 
                    ]{mystyle} 
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{theorem}
```

But `ntheorem` should be the better solution because it "respects" page breaks.